How to convert input 'text' in particular date format like 'dd-MM-yyyy'
I have date string value in input text and I want to convert that text and display in 'dd-MM-yyyy' format in that input. How to convert it?
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="orderDateInput" value="11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM">


I suppose you can use this question to format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript

But my input is text and date field

You can use regular expressions:


const regex = /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/;
const value = '11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM'
const newValue = value.replace(regex, (_, month, day, year) => {
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`
})
console.log(newValue) // 15/11/2017 12:00:00 AM




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If the expected input is always in the form 11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM, i. e. with the date part written with / as separator, then the target string can be extracted like


function toDateStr(s){
 const [m,d,y]=s.match(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/)[0].split("/");
 return [d,m,y].join("/");
}


console.log(["11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM","the date is 12/27/2019"].map(toDateStr))




In the Netherlands they use this data format dd-mm-yyyy with hyphens. So, if you create a data object from the string using the Date() constructor and then "toString" it with toLocaleDateString() you can format the data more or less as you like. Here I use "nl-NL" for the ordering and using the hyphens, and then an options object that specifies how year, month and day should be displayed.


let form = document.forms.form01;

let dateobj = new Date(form.orderDateInput.value);

const options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit'
};

form.date.value = dateobj.toLocaleDateString('nl-NL', options);
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orderDateInput"
  name="orderDateInput" value="11/15/2017 12:00:00 AM">
  <output name="date"></output>
</form>



